# pushNavigator - Dart/Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Olá, estou aprendendo a desenvolver apps em Dart/Flutter.

O que acontece, é que carreguei um Navigator.push, onde ele carrega a rota anterior, caso eu queira voltar, porém, na minha appbar ao invés de carregar o botão de voltar, ele inicializa o botão que abre o Navigator Drawer.

Abaixo o código e imagem do que ocorre:

Nav.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    Future push(BuildContext context, Widget page, {bool replace = false}) {

    if(replace) {
      return Navigator.pushReplacement(
     context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return page;
    }));
   }
   return Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return page;
   }));
  }
```

List_view.dart

```
  _body(context){
return Observer(
    //stream: _carMobx.stream,
    builder: (context){

      List<Carro> carros = _carMobx.carros;
        if(_carMobx.error != null){
          return TextError("Não foi possível retornar os dados\n\nClique Aqui para recarregar", onPressed: _fetch());
        }
        else{
          if(carros == null){
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }else {
            return _listView(context, carros);
          }
        }
  }
  );
  }

  Container _listView(context, List<Carro> carros) {
   return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
  child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: carros.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        Carro c = carros[index];
        return Card(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                    child: Image.network(c.urlFoto ?? 
        "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/63/dc/de/63dcde7857ba4c976db71314fc79cf19.jpg",
                      width: 250,)
                ),
                Text(c.nome ?? "Sem nome",
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                ),
                Text(c.descricao ?? "Sem Descrição",
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,),
                ),
                ButtonBarTheme(
                  data: ButtonBarThemeData(),
                  child: ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('DETALHES'),
                        onPressed: () => _onClickDetalhes(context, c),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('COMPARTILHAR'),
                        onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
      );
      }

      _onClickDetalhes(context, Carro c) {
        push(context, CarroPage(c));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro o seu problema, e o código que você postou não ajuda muito, de qualquer maneira pelo que eu entendi você precisa mudar o icone que aparece na AppBar, de maneira que te permita retornar a rota precedente e não o icone para abrir o menu, certo?

Se este é o seu caso, na sua nova rota você deve haver um **Scaffold** e adicionar um novo AppBar com o botão de retorno, exemplo:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Segunda pagina'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => {
             // Chame o Navigator aqui para voltar a rota precedente
          }
        ),
      ),
);
```

Você pode encontrar este exato exemplo na documentação oficial [aqui](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)